# Stuck with weird error after upgrading to angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript

I upgraded to Angular 14 and now suddenly, I am getting error like below:

[image]

Now, I dont know what is causing this because the error is not at all explanatory. I am also seeing below warning message when start my server locally:

[image]

Can someone please give me hint ? I looked at the polyfill.js which is generated by angular-cli. I dont see any issue in my current project.

Please please help

Comment: Looks like you’re running in prod mode here?

Comment: I am doing `ng server`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start tackling this problem by removing node_modules and package-lock.json file from the app folder and reinstall a few things from scratch:

1. `npm install -g typescript@latest` (to ensure you have a newer version than ES5)
2. `npm install` (for the rest of the modules)